# Creating a calculated column that references another calculated column

Tags: sql, databricks

I'm working in Databricks in SQL and im creating a bunch of columns with long equations, what I would like to do is use the calculated column as a reference/variable in other calculated columns.

**EXAMPLE of some code I have**:

```
Select
Premium as Premium,
Premium + B as Premium1,
Premium + B + C as Premium2,
Premium + B + C + D as Premium3
from TABLENAME
```

**What I want to achieve**:

```
Select
Premium as Premium
Premium + B as Premium1,
Premium1 + C as Premium2, (where Premium1 = Premium + B which we created)
Premium2 + D as Premium3
from TABLENAME
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks?

Comment: You cannot reference computed values via their alias like this in SQL because the alias doesn't "exist" until the dataset is generated.  The only way to accomplish this is with nested subqueries or a chain of CTEs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as a chain of CTEs like this:

```
with 
   p1 as (
       select premium, premium + B as premium1
       from tablename
   ),
   p2 as (
       select premium, premium1, premium1 + C as premium2
       from p1
   ),
   p3 as (
       select premium, premium1, premium2, premium2 + D as premium3
       from p2
   )
select
    *
from 
    p3
```